# How to validate regular expressions in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba, validation

Our customer provides hundreds of regular expressions in an excel file that we need to add in our SQL Server to do pattern matching in database, but many times they send invalid or broken regular expression in their excel file.

We validate the regular expressions in c# by instantiating Regex object with given regular expression, if it is incorrect then error is caught in catch block and we know which expression is invalid.

```
 try
  {
    var test = new Regex(rule.RegexExpression);
  }
 catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Errors.Add("Error in " + rule.Id)
  }
```

**Problem:**
It gets too late in knowing which regular expressions are incorrect until developer validates data given by customer.

**Question:**
Is there a way in which our customer can validate hundreds of regular expression with a click of a button in excel (something like VBA macro button). I tried VBA Regex, I couldn't validate the regular expression itself.

Any help or clue is appreciated.

Comment: How exactly are the expressions being evaluated in SQL server?  If you want the customer to do the validation then presumably they'd need access to the same execution environment in order to perform the testing.

Comment: ^^ and for supported syntax to be the same.

Comment: FWIW the `Ex` in `RegEx` stands for "Expression" - `RegexExpression` thus stands for "Regular Expression Expression"

Comment: VBScript regex and .NET regex are different, and if your expressions use named capture groups or lookbehinds, VBScript regex engine won't be able to evaluate them: one solution could be to deploy a COM-visible DLL whose TLB (COM type library) your client's VBA code can reference and call into, so that the expressions are validated using the same regex engine.

Comment: @TimWilliams we are using CLR function in SQL server to use regex and match strings in our texts. We don't want customer to do any test, just want an easy way (like a button click in Excel) for them to validate regex they are providing.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you, I know, I just wrote it for more clarity, but it backfired :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: you mean the Regex eg: \b(residen(ce|tial)|a house|a home)\b are different in VB and .NET?

Comment: no, that would be fine (capture groups are ok); it's *named* capture groups that aren't supported. However, if the client's regex is valid in VBScript, it's going to be valid in .NET - but the inverse isn't necessarily true.